# Any way to control toolbars from Notes form

Tags: lotus-notes

I've got a form with an embedded view, showing a single category.  
The single category comes from a radio button at the top of the form.
When focus is on the form (eg. when click the radio button) a toolbar appears at the top, & page moves down.
When you click into the embedded view, the toolbar disappears, & page moves up.
The page moving up/down, as the toolbar appears/disappears, is visually jarring for the user.
I thought of a line that might show/hide and prevent the movement, but the onblur event of the radio button field is not triggered when focus goes to the embedded view, and I can't see any other way to detect focus moving between form & embedded view.
Any ideas on how to either:
a) Trigger some script with focus going to/from embedded view (so I can show/hide a line)?  or
b) Stop (programatically) the toolbar from appearing when this form is in edit mode?  or
c) Have a toolbar of some kind appear when focus is on the embedded view?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this can only be controlled by user preferences in the Notes client.

Notes has an option "Show Toolbars Only When Editing" (in the menu View -> Toolbar), which can be turned on or off by the user. I think the option is on by default, and has exactly the effect you describe: with focus on a form in edit mode, toolbars appear, but moving focus to something else causes toolbars to disappear.

I'd be inclined to instruct users how to change the option if that behaviour bothers them. It might also be possible to set the option by Domino policies, but not sure.

Comment: I had thought of that but was reluctant to go that way due to the need to roll out the setting. I just had a look now (didn't realise it was as easy as View/Toolbar) and it does work, but also leaves a toolbar visible at all times. I guess if I can't find another way to do it I might have to consider doing this.  Thanks for your input.